# hard disk not mounting

Tags: 14.04, mount, hard-drive, raid, ntfs

it shows error like

Error mounting `/dev/sdb1` at

```
/media/mrityunjay/LENOVO_USB_HDD: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/mrityunjay/LENOVO_USB_HDD"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Failed to read vcn 0x4: Input/output error
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware
```

. In the first case run `chkdsk /f` on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the `/f` parameter is very
important! If the device is a `SoftRAID/FakeRAID` then first activate
it and mount a different device under the `/dev/mapper/` directory, (e.g.
`/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1`). Please see the `dmraid` documentation
for more details.

Comment: Could you please write what your question is? Is it "how do I mount it on Ubuntu?" or "Why is it not working?" (for which the reason is written there). Does the drive work on other operating systems?

Answer (score 1):

On your external harddrive, the master file table (MFT) and its copy (MFTMirr) are seemingly no longer consistent.

You might want to fix it using the Linux tool `ntfsfix` on the command line.

Connect the hard drive to your System.Open a terminal by <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>.
 To sum it up Enter

`sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1`

in the terminal and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You will be asked for your password. Enter that and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again.

and you will be good to go. Hope it helps.

Comment: AFAIK `ntfsfix` *does not* repair inconsistencies between `$MFT` and `$MFTMirr`. According to its [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/ntfsfix.8.html) «ntfsfix is NOT a Linux version of chkdsk.  It only repairs some  fundamental  NTFS inconsistencies,  resets  the  NTFS  journal file and schedules an NTFS consistency check for the first boot into Windows»